# Get the path specified in the source of file section

Tags: inno-setup

Is there any way by which we can get the path of the source file in [file] section be made available in [code] section. I need to have the full path as been given in the source. I need to check it with the content of a file and if the path is present in the file, then only i need to copy that particular file. I am using Check: in the file section and need to have the whole path of file made available in code section for comparison.

Comment: can anyone help please..... i searched in web for this particular problem, and was not able to get any answer. Kindly help me

Comment: Maybe try the inno setup newsgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the chosen install folder from pascal script, you can use either `ExpandConstant('{app}')` or `WizardDirValue()`. Note that I don't think the returned path contains a trailing backslash.

This would simply check a file existence:

```
function IsMyFilePresent: Boolean;
begin
    Result:=FileExists(ExpandConstant('{app}\filename.ext'));
end;
```

If it's an ini file, you can use this code to retrieve the data of certain keys inside it:

(example using `WizardDirValue()`)

```
inifile:=WizardDirValue()+'\filename.ext';
MyString:=GetIniString('SectionName', 'KeyName', 'DefaultValue', inifile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the [`CurrentFileName()`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_currentfilename.htm) function that:

> Returns the destination name of the [Files] entry that is currently being processed.

You can probably work out the source from this. I'm not sure how it handles wildcards though (but I suspect it just returns "blah/*"